# Get the StatusCode of NegotiatedContentResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

How do you check if the `NegotiatedContentResult` from this `IHttpActionResult` has an `Ok StatusCode`.

Ex. `if (ValidateRegistrationStep3(accountModel) == Ok()) { code to run }`

```
var result = ValidateRegistrationStep3(accountModel);
```

If you examine `result` in `Locals` it has a `Value` of `System.Web.Http.Results.NegotiatedContentResult<string>` of `Type` `System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult {System.Web.Http.Results.NegotiatedContentResult<string>}` with a `StatusCode` of `OK`.  How do I check the `StatusCode`?

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("register/validate3")]
public IHttpActionResult ValidateRegistrationStep3(
            [FromBody]AccountRegisterModel accountModel) {
    List<string> errors = new List<string>();

    if (!IsDigits(accountModel.CreditCard, 16)) errors.Add("CreditCard needs to be 16 digits.");

    var regExp = @"^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/[0-9]{2}$";
    if (!Regex.IsMatch(accountModel.ExpDate, regExp, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                    errors.Add("Expiration Date is not valid format (MM/YY)");

    if (errors.Count == 0) return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Register Model-3 Valid");
    else return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, errors.ToArray()); }
```

**Solution:**

Break the validation code out to a helper method and then call it from the `IHttpActionResult`.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("register/validate3")]
public IHttpActionResult ValidateRegistrationStep3(
            [FromBody]AccountRegisterModel accountModel) {
    List<string> errors = ValidateRegistrationStep3Inner(accountModel);

    if (errors.Count == 0) return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Register Model-3 Valid");
    else return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, errors.ToArray()); }

private List<string> ValidateRegistrationStep3Inner(AccountRegisterModel accountModel)
{
  List<string> errors = new List<string>();

  if (!IsDigits(accountModel.CreditCard, 16)) errors.Add("CreditCard needs to be 16 digits.");
  if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(accountModel.ExpDate)) {
    var regExp = @"^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/[0-9]{2}$";
    if (!Regex.IsMatch(accountModel.ExpDate, regExp, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
      errors.Add("Expiration Date is not valid format (MM/YY)");
  } else errors.Add("Expiration Date is required (MM/YY)");

  return errors; }
```

The helper method can then be called from within the `Controller` and it's return checked.

```
if (ValidateRegistrationStep1Inner(accountModel).Count == 0 &&
            ValidateRegistrationStep2Inner(accountModel).Count == 0 &&
            ValidateRegistrationStep3Inner(accountModel).Count == 0)
```

Comment: Where are you calling the controller action like that? You're not going to get the StatusCode because the action is returning `IHttpActionResult` not `NegotiatedContentResult`

Comment: See my updated question.  How do I check the StatusCode of the IHttpActonResult?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question -- you'd need to execute the result.

```
public async Task<HttpStatusCode> GetResult()
{
    var response = ValidateRegistrationStep3(accountModel);
    var result = await response.ExecuteAsync(new CancellationToken());
    var statusCode = result.StatusCode;

    return statusCode;
}
```

But you shouldn't ever need to call a controller directly yourself. Instead, move the validation code to a separate class (or add a new method that doesn't involve `IHttpActionResult`).

```
public class RegistrationValidation : IRegistrationValidation
{
    public List<string> Validate(AccountRegisterModel model)
    {
        List<string> errors = new List<string>();

        ...

        return errors;
    }
}

public class RegistrationController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IRegistrationValidation validator;

    // with a DI container
    public RegistrationController(IRegistrationValidation validator)
    {
        this.validator = validator;
    }

    // without a DI container
    public RegistrationController()
    {
        this.validator = new RegistrationValidation();
    }

    public IHttpActionResult ValidateRegistrationStep3(AccountRegisterModel accountModel)
    {
        var errors = validator.Validate(accountModel);

        if (error.Count() == 0)
            return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Register Model-3 Valid");
        ...
    }

    public IHttpActionResult FinishRegistration(AccountRegisterModel accountModel)
    {
        var errors = validator.Validate(accountModel);
        if (errors.Count() == 0)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An async method was not practical but breaking the validation code out into a helper method and then calling and checking it avoids the original problem.  See my Solution in the the OP.